# why CrystalReportViewer using ODBC connection prompt for credentials

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, odbc

I'm loading a Crystal report in a CrystalReportView in C# for a  .net 4.8 Windows form , using a  32 bits System  DSN ODBC  with the controller "MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI  Driver"    connection version 8.0 via TCP/IP . (it pass the test connection with the given credential).  from the application using the ODBC connection i'm able to do a select to a required table and load the data into a datagridview  (the same table that the report use) without need to provide any credential. But when i use the same ODBC connection with the report, it keeps prompting for user a password to establish the connection which is not the desired result.  and even if i provide the right requested credentials it keeps prompting for credential without been able to load the report.

the sole purpose of the " QueryTable_Click" is to prove that there was no MySQL User Privileges issue,Firewall and Network Issues,ODBC Driver Version Compatibility issue or wrong ODBC DSN Configuration. it work fine. so i do not know what else to look at.

Crystalreport 2013 Support pack 5  version : 14.1.5.1501

```
    private string connectionString = "DSN=sANSSIMysql8032;";

    private void LoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {

            try
            {

                // Open the connection
                connection.Open();

                // Load the Crystal Report

                reportDocument.Load(@"D:\ReportesCrystal\MySqlReport1.rpt");

                // Set the ODBC connection information for the report
                ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
                {
                    ServerName = connectionString // Use the ODBC DSN as the server name
                    // You can set other connection properties if necessary
                };

                // Apply the connection information to all tables in the report
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
                {
                    TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                    tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
                    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                }

                // Set the report to CrystalReportViewer
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
            }
            catch (OdbcException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de base de datos: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (CrystalReportsException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de Crystal Reports: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (LogOnException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Crystal Reports LogOn Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error general: " + ex.Message);
            }
       
            finally
            {
              
                // Close the connection after use
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void QueryTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create connection
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                // Open the connection
                connection.Open();

                // Create a command to execute the query
                string query = "SELECT * FROM hotels";
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);

                // Create a data adapter to fill the dataset
                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

                // Fill the dataset with the results of the query
                adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Hotels");

                // Bind the dataset to a DataGridView (assuming you have a DataGridView named dataGridView1)
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Hotels"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur during the process
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the connection after use
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```